# tracking user interaction Android

Tags: android

I am new in Android and is developing an app which runs in background as service to collect user activity. till now my app is able to get information about Time_Start, Time_End and Name of other app used by user.

I want to improve my app to be able to count how many interactions(like user tap, touch,...) user make while using other app.
any help?
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count interactions with screen in Android phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994310/count-interactions-with-screen-in-android-phone)

Comment: You already asked this question, please don't spam the forums by asking it again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994310/count-interactions-with-screen-in-android-phone

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK one **can't** catch touch events/key presses if they are *outside* your Activity's context or Application's context. I think it goes ***against*** the design principle in general ( every app. is sandboxed in its own DVM).

Also, Android has provided mechanism of Intents to track some specific *actions* and not evry interaction the user has with the mobile . So, I don't think it seems possible .